# Import data from mdb file to mysql database can not upload data

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

I'm using PHP code to upload or insert data from MDB file to MySQL database.I want my table value get inserted into MySQL database. But data does not inserted into MySQL database.This code shows me no error.Here is my code. please help I have tried every solution on net.

```
 <?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $dbname = 'payroll_system';

    //mysql
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM attendance";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    //mdb
    $conn2 = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO"); 
    $conn2->Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\payroll\\eTimeTrackLite1.mdb");
    $rs = $conn2->Execute("SELECT * FROM AttendanceLogs");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
                    {

                        $column1=$row["AttendanceLogId"];$column2=$row["AttendanceDate"];$column3=$row["EmployeeId"];$column4=$row["InTime"];
                        $column6=$row["OutTime"];$column8=$row["Duration"];
                        echo "hello";
                        echo $column1;echo $column2;echo $column3;echo $column4;
                        $rs->MoveFirst();
                        while (!$rs->EOF) 
                        {
                        $attendance_id = $rs->Fields("AttendanceLogId");
                        $attendance_date = $rs->Fields("AttendanceDate");
                        $emp_id = $rs->Fields("EmployeeId");
                        $in_time = $rs->Fields("InTime");
                        $out_time = $rs->Fields("OutTime");
                        $duration = $rs->Fields("Duration");
                        mysql_query("UPDATE attendance SET AttendanceLogId = '$attendance_id', AttendanceDate='$attendance_date', EmployeeId='$emp_id',InTime='$in_time',OutTime='$out_time',Duration='$duration'  '"); ?>

                            <?php


                        $rs->MoveNext();
                        }

                    }               
        ?>
        </table> <?php
       mysql_free_result($result);
        $rs->Close();
        $conn2->Close();
        $rs = null;
        $conn2 = null;



    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to `INSERT` each records data instead of `UPDATE`. Re-write the following line:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE attendance SET AttendanceLogId = '$attendance_id', AttendanceDate='$attendance_date', EmployeeId='$emp_id',InTime='$in_time',OutTime='$out_time',Duration='$duration'  '");
```